# Salesforce Marketing Cloud SOAP API - Retrieve a File Transfer Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap

Is there a way to retrieve a File Transfer Activity using the SFMC SOAP API?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/filetransferactivity.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The only method available on the FileTransferActivity object is the "Perform" method. A list of objects and methods applicable to each is given in this [Salesforce Developers page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/supported_operations_for_objects_and_methods.htm) on the subject.

Comment: My only disagreement here is that I don't trust the SFMC dev page (which I could've just put in my question). That documentation has been wrong on numerous occasions, including Automation objects (there's essentially a secret menu of object names) and numerous, important typos.

Well, not so much a disagreement. I'm just curious if anyone's found some "secret menu" for these. Oh well. Thanks!

Comment: I feel your pain. The page is a bit of a disgrace and the SOAP docs have errors, omissions and out of date info in abundance. I pointed out a bunch of issues with the info on this page a year ago and got knocked back. The team covering docs in Indy seems stretched and the platform's a deceptively broad and fast moving subject for one or two technical writers to keep across. I'd favour something that looks a little more like a Wiki where the likes of members of this forum can help maintain it at scale. I use this page & the WSDL as a starting point, then use a Describe call on the object.

Comment: @jacobhobson did you ever figure this out? Im trying to create a FileTransferActivity via the SOAP api and maybe you can help https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/320366/create-a-filetransferactivity-via-soap-api

Comment: @colins44 There is a bunch of movement, here. It's not documented, but take a look at the REST route /automation/v1/rest. It's a minefield, but ostensibly has GETs, POSTs, PUTs, PATCHs etc