# Create A FileTransferActivity via SOAP API

Tags: soap-api, ftp

I'm trying to create a FileTransferActivity using the SOAP API. According to the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/supported_operations_for_objects_and_methods.htm), it should be possible to both create and perform a FileTransferActivity, but no examples are given.

This is what my current SOAP envelope looks like:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Body>
    <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <Options/>
      <Objects xsi:type="FileTransferActivity">
        <Name>TestinFileTransferActivity</Name>
        <PartnerProperties>
          <FileTransferLocationID>e4c11cbd-7826-459b-9953-5b878ea329c2</FileTransferLocationID>
          <Name>FileTransferTest</Name>
          <Description>FileTransferTest</Description>
          <CustomerKey>FileTransferText</CustomerKey>
          <FileSpec>testing.csv</FileSpec>
          <IsActive>true</IsActive>
          <IsEncrypted>false</IsEncrypted>
          <IsCompressed>false</IsCompressed>
          <IsSigned>false</IsSigned>
          <MaxFileAge>0</MaxFileAge>
          <IsUpload>true</IsUpload>
          <IsPgp>false</IsPgp>
          <IsFileSpecLocalized>false</IsFileSpecLocalized>
          <MaxImportFrequency>0</MaxImportFrequency>
          <MaxFileAgeScheduleOffset>0</MaxFileAgeScheduleOffset>
        </PartnerProperties>
      </Objects>
    </CreateRequest>
  </Body>
  <Header>
    <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{AuthTokenIsHere}}</fueloauth>
  </Header>
</Envelope>
```

When I use the above envelope and the create method I get the error

```
[
  {
    "StatusCode": "Error",
    "StatusMessage": "Error",
    "OrdinalID": "0",
    "ErrorCode": "9999999",
    "NewID": "0",
    "Object": {
      "PartnerKey": "",
      "PartnerProperties": {
        "Name": "FileTransferTest"
      },
      "ObjectID": "",
      "Name": "TestinFileTransferActivity"
    }
  }
]
```

Which is not proving to be too helpful.

I am wondering if anyone has created a FileTransferActivity using the SOAP API and can help me out?

Comment: Not documented, but see the automation/v1/rest route to see the methods available on File Transfers. SOAP's not going to work here.

Comment: So this is not possible at all using SOAP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Macca's comment you will find an undocumented endpoint:

> automation/v1/filetransfers

Here is a code example based on your values:

```
var payload = {
        Name: 'TestinFileTransferActivity',
        CustomerKey: 'TestinFileTransferActivity',
        FileTransferLocationId: "e4c11cbd-7826-459b-9953-5b878ea329c2",
        Description: "FileTransferTest",
        FileSpec: 'testing.csv'
    };

var token = --getToken--,
    header = {
        header: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + token
        }
    };

httpRequest('POST',"https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/automation/v1/filetransfers","application/json",payload,header);
```